# how to loop a function in python that return a response?

Tags: python, function, loops, pdfkit

In the function response it will produce a PDF

```
def export_to_pdf(disc):
    print disc
    rendered = render_template('specsheet.html', specs=disc)
    css = ['templates/style.css']
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False, css=css)
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
    return response


def getproducts():
    a = conn.cursor()
    a.execute("SELECT * FROM `products` order by id asc")
    getdatas = a.fetchall()


    for x in range(0,len(getdatas)):
        time.sleep(5)
        disc = {
            'name': getdatas[x][1], 'wattage': getdatas[x][2],
            'lumens': getdatas[x][3], 'cct': getdatas[x][4],
            'inputv': getdatas[x][5], 'powerfac': getdatas[x][6],
            'efficacy': getdatas[x][7], 'cri': getdatas[x][8],
            'projectedhr': getdatas[x][9],
            'dimensions': getdatas[x][10], 'beamangle': getdatas[x][11],
            'operatintemp': getdatas[x][12], 'certificates':getdatas[x][13],
            'waterproof':getdatas[x][14], 'warranty': getdatas[x][15],
            'ce': getdatas[x][16], 'dlc': getdatas[x][17],
            'energy':getdatas[x][18], 'etl': getdatas[x][19],
            'fcc':getdatas[x][20], 'rohs': getdatas[x][21],
            'ul': getdatas[x][22], 'cul': getdatas[x][23],
            'proimg': getdatas[x][24], 'dimen':getdatas[x][25]
        }

        export_to_pdf(disc)

    return "Success"
```

The export_to_pdf(disc) function will generate a pdf, but in this case it goes throgh the function but didn,t generate  any PDF

Comment: So what do you expect it to do? You're not using the returned content from your function, and you're iterating over several PDFs, while attempting to return a single HTTP response (there can only be one response to a particular HTTP request)

Comment: You are not even storing return value of  `export_to_pdf`. Furthermore, you are calling `export_to_pdf` multiple times.

Comment: It generates a PDF (or several) but you are not doing anything with them. What you are returning at the end is "Success" and none of the pdfs.

Comment: Do you want to return 1 pdf with all products or 1 pdf for each product?

Comment: 1 pdf for each product